# progress indicator for bash script without dialog or pv

Tags: bash

I've written a bash script to truncate through a server list and perform various commands. I would like to incorporate a progress indicator like a percent complete while the script is running. I found a script online to perform this but it's not working properly and I am unsure how to utilize it.

The dialog command is not an option here as I am working with nsh

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while [[ $i -lt 11 ]]; do
##
##  \r = carriage return
##  \c = suppress linefeed
##
echo -en "\r$i%\c\b"
(( i=i+1 ))
sleep 1
done

echo

exit 0
```

For testing purposes I am only connecting to each server and echoing the hostname.

```
for i in $(cat serverlist.txt)
do
nexec -i hostname
done
```

How can I utilize the first code snipped to show the progress while going through the list of servers in the code above?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: ...and you're relying heavily on `echo` behavior that's not just an extension to POSIX, but actually conflicts with the standard. Consider `printf` instead.

Comment: Depending on what you are outputting here you might be able to (ab)use `pv` for this.

Comment: I was about to suggest `pv` as well. `dialog` also provides a built-in progress bar widget.

Comment: ...see the question this is closed as a duplicate of for an example of the `dialog` approach.

Comment: You recommend not using a for loop to read a list. However, when using a while loop it only reads in the first line. I am running commands on a solaris machine to determine if ufs or zfs storage is present and then finding the location of the luns as well as running some zpool commands. I doubt that pv would work in this situation.

Comment: Why wouldn't pv work? You can feed it a completely arbitrary pipeline -- it's not like the examples showing things like tarred output are the only possible use case; you can feed it one carriage return per host you run a command to, tell it that the total file size is equal to your number of hosts, and there you are.

Comment: ...now, if the real issue is that you're targeting a platform that doesn't have pv or dialog available, that's a thing you need to include in your question -- would distinguish it from similar questions that already exist, making it no longer a duplicate.

Comment: re: "when using a while loop it only reads in the first line" -- that means that  something else (presumably `nexec`) is reading the rest of stdin, thus making it no longer available. Easy way to do that is to loop over a different FD.

Comment: What is this "nsh"? If your scripting environment isn't really bash, you shouldn't be using the bash tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
write_status() {
  done=0
  total=$1
  columns=${COLUMNS:-100}

  # print initial, empty progress bar
  for (( i=0; i<columns; i++ )); do printf '-'; done; printf '\r'

  # every time we read a line, print a progress bar with one more item complete
  while read -r; do
    done=$(( done + 1 ))
    pct=$(( done * columns / total ))
    for ((i=0; i<pct; i++)); do
      printf '+'
    done
    for ((i=pct; i<columns; i++)); do
      printf '-'
    done
    printf '\r'
    if (( done == total )); then break; fi
  done 
}

# read server names into an array; the below is bash 4.x syntax
readarray -t servers <serverlist.txt

# direct FD 4 to the a subshell running the write_status function
exec 4> >(write_status "${#servers[@]}")

for hostname in "${servers[@]}"; do
  nexec -i "$hostname"  # actually run the command
  echo >&4              # ...and notify write_status that it completed
done
```

If you wanted to parallelize the remote commands, you can do that by replacing the `for` loop at the bottom with the following:

```
for hostname in "${servers[@]}"; do
  (nexec -i "$hostname"; echo >&4) &
done
wait
```

If your shell is a version of bash prior to 4.0, then the `readarray -t servers <serverlist` can be replaced with the following:

```
servers=( )
while IFS= read -r server; do servers+=( "$server" ); done <serverlist.txt
```

Comment: This appears to work with some modifications. readarray apparently doesn't work with nsh. One question, however. How does $1 from the write_status function contain the number of items from the text file?

Comment: @ramblinman, because `"${#servers[@]}"` is passed as the first argument to `write_status`, and is the length of the `servers` array.

Answer (score 1):

To keep track of your progress, you'll want to store the list of servers in an array, so you know how many there are:

```
mapfile -t servers <serverlist.txt    # servers is an array
n=${#servers[@]}                      # how many

i=0
for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
    ((i++))
    progress=$(( i * 100 / n )) 
    nexec ...
    echo "you are ${progress}% complete"
done
```

Comment: Much better in terms of following best-practices, but doesn't quite do the updated-in-place progress bar the OP is looking for.

Comment: No, but how noisy is "nexec"? The OP can add the bells and whistles

Comment: Note that bash can only accomplish integer arithmetic, so it's important to do the multiplication before the division.

Comment: As I read it, the question is all about adding bells and whistles.

Comment: Yes, the nexec is noisy. Like the original post mentioned, I cleaned up the original code to make it easier for me to test. My script runs multiple commands and then creates some local directories and creates a report. Nothing is printed/echoed to the screen while the script is running.